# C++ Library to Intel Mac Driver

Tags: c++, macos, intel, pci, soundcard

I'm completely new to programming. I need to "convert" a C++ library to Intel Mac driver so I can run my old PCI soundcards on my (Hackintosh) Snow Leopard.

My cards are Echoaudio's MiaMIDI and Mona. From their site, I can get the library. This is what they say at the download page:

> Interested in writing your own driver
>   for Echo’s hardware? Then you need the
>   generic driver code. This is the
>   cross-platform C++ library used for
>   our Windows and Mac PCI and Cardbus
>   drivers.

Would you please point me to the right direction what should I do with this library? Can I do it in xCode?

[Here's the link](http://echoaudio.com/Downloads/Developer.php) to the download page.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're completely new to programming, then I'm afraid you're looking at a *very* steep learning curve (more of a learning cliff, in all honesty) as far as writing device drivers is considered.

Comment: In addition the only way you can use a PCI card in an Intel Apple system is either in a Mac Pro or some kind of FrankenMac .. If its the former you certainly have money to burn to buy a supported sound card.  If its the latter then there are other forums that may help you use your particular card (such as superuser.com for starters)

Comment: @middaparka: I know it's kinda scarry but I'm willing to try.

Comment: @Peter M: Thanks for pointing superuser.com, just posted the same question there. And yes, I use FrankenMac/Hackintosh, I edited my question.

Comment: Hehe, good luck!  "I'm new to engineering, how do I build a suspension bridge?"

Comment: @Baron Don't get me wrong (I'm not trying to put you off), I'd just be tempted to try something a little less ambitious first. Either way, I hope it goes well. :-)

Comment: @Baron: Did you read the source code that you downloaded? That would be the obvious starting point. Also: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @AshleysBrain: Wow, it's that difficult? :(

Comment: @middaparka: It's those unused soundcards that move me. Thanks :)

Comment: @bk1e: Thanks a lot. Now, at least, I know where to start, I guess.

Comment: Basically to debug in kernel world (where drivers live) you need 2 separate machines and enter kernel debugging mode on the target machine.